# How to use Chisel for Port Forwarding?

Tags: port-forwarding, pivoting

I'm getting started learning pentesting and I came across this situation.

- **Privilege Escalation**

Running WinPeas I noticed a change to escalation bypass UAC. I was thinking to use a local exploit (Kali) with Chisel forwarding this traffic for HackBox Machine. Is it possible?

```
+-------------+                                             +--------------+
|             |                                             |              |
|   Kali      +---------------------------------------------+   HackBox    |
|             |                                             |              |
|             |                                             |              |
+-------------+                                             +--------------+
```

Kali Chisel is listening on port 8000
HackBox connect Chisel Server and accept all remote traffic from port 444 to 444 local

Commands:

```
chisel server -p 8000 -reverse
chisel client kali:8000 R:444:localhost:444
```

I would like to know if this mindset is correct.